# Why multiply by 2 when calculating partial derivatives during backpropagation?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, backpropagation, mathematics

I'm wondering why we multiple by 2 when calculating partial derivatives.

I'm referencing the 2's that I've circled below, from [here](https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gradient_descent.html).

[image]

We also see this in the python implementation,
`m_deriv += -2*X[i] * (Y[i] - (m*X[i] + b))`, there is a 2.

How can I understand the intuition here?

My math is not strong so apologies in advance if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the Mean Square Error $\Sigma\frac{1}{N}(y-(Wx+b))^2$as the loss function, if you take the derivative, you will have the $2$. In some materials, we will use $\frac{1}{2}\Sigma\frac{1}{N}(y-(Wx+b))^2$ as the loss function to cancel out the $2$. In fact, this doesn't matter at all and it has no impacts on params optimization.